# How to declare an object created by a class loaded by classloader

Tags: java

I have to use a classloader to load a class from a custom jar file, and the following works:

```
Class<?> JasperPrint = urlClassLoader.loadClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint");
```

How to I declare an object I create with the constructor?  Below, Eclipse complains that JasperPrint is not an object:

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperPrint.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Also just to declare an object without instantiating, since the following also does not work:

```
JasperPrint jp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JasperPrint is not a class. It is a variable holding the loaded Class definition net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint.
On a Class instance you can call newInstance() to create a new instance using the no-arg constructor:

```
Class<?> jasperPrintClazz = urlClassLoader.loadClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint");
Object jasperPrint = jasperPrintClazz.newInstance();
```

Variable jasperPrint is an instance (object) of type JasperPrint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a class dynamically you do not know it's static type (at compilation type). You can either cast it to a `JasperPrint`'s interface if you have it on your classpath when compiling your code. Otherwise you will need to use reflection to call the newly created object's methods.